# Implementing a catamorphism for Expression Trees

Tags: haskell, catamorphism

I am trying to implement an expression tree in Haskell as follows:

```hl
data ExprTr a b = 
                 Variable a 
                | Constant b 
                | Add (ExprTr a b) (ExprTr a b) 
                | Mul (ExprTr a b) (ExprTr a b)
                deriving (Eq, Show)
```

And I would like to be able to implement operations on it using a catamorphism.

Currently, this is the function I got:

```hl
cataTr f _ _ _ (Variable i) = f i
cataTr f g _ _ (Constant i) = g i
cataTr f g h i (Add e1 e2) = g (cataTr f g h i e1) (cataTr f g h i e2)
cataTr f g h i (Mul e1 e2) = h (cataTr f g h i e1) (cataTr f g h i e2)
```

However, whenever I try to use it with an expresion of type `ExprTr String Integer` I get compiler errors. For example, running `cataTr id id id id (Var "X")` returns the following compiler error instead of `(Var "X")`.

```
Couldn't match type 'Integer' with '[Char]'
    Expected type: 'ExprTr String String'
    Actual type: 'ExprTr String Integer'
```

I am not sure how to proceed. Furthermore, I would appreciate some suggestions on how to type such a function as cataTr to make it easier to debug later.

As I am fairly new to Haskell, I would like to understand how to approach such situations from 'first principles' instead of using a library to generate the catamorphism for myself.

Comment: The catamorphism is correct (well there is a typo, but I guess that is in the question), you can however not use `cataTr id id id id`, since the first and second id both need to return a value of the return type, and the first function takes an object of type `a`, whereas the latter takes one from type `b`, if both are different then there is a problem.

Comment: The names `f g h i` are  hard to remember. It's easier if you name them after the constructors, e.g. `cataTr variable constant add mul (...) = ....`. After that, it's matter of replacing `Variable` with `variable`, `Constant` with `constant`, `Add` with `add`, and `Mul` with `mul`, which feels very natural.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is *expected behavior*.

You made a typo in the question I guess, since you should use `h` and `i` as functions:

```
cataTr f _ _ _ (Variable i) = f i
cataTr f g _ _ (Constant i) = g i
cataTr f g h i (Add e1 e2) = h (cataTr f g h i e1) (cataTr f g h i e2)
cataTr f g h i (Mul e1 e2) = i (cataTr f g h i e1) (cataTr f g h i e2)
```

or likely more elegant:

```
cataTr f g h i = go
    where go (Variable i) = f i
          go (Constant i) = g i
          go (Add e1 e2) = h (go e1) (go e2)
          go (Mul e1 e2) = i (go e1) (go e2)
```

or as [@DanielWagner suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64178693/implementing-a-catamorphism-for-expression-trees/64178802?noredirect=1#comment113491891_64178802), with a `case` expression:

```
cataTr f g h i = go
    where go v = case v of
              Variable i -> f i
              Constant i -> g i
              Add e1 e2 -> h (go e1) (go e2)
              Mul e1 e2 -> i (go e1) (go e2)
```

Nevertheless, you can not call the function `cataTr` with `id` as third and fourth parameter. These functions require two parameters. Furthermore if `a` and `b` are different the two first parameters can not be both `id`, since your `f` maps an `a` to the result type, and the `g` maps a `b` to the result type.

You can for example pass the data constructor to construct an identity function with:

```
cataTr Variable Constant Add Mul (Variable "X")
```

this will thus yield `Variable "X"` again, or you can for example map all `Variable`s to `0` with `const 0`, and use `id`, `(+)` and `(*)` to evaluate an expression:

```
cataTr (const 0) id (+) (*) (Variable "X")
```

Comment: Proposal: in the more elegant version, use `cataTr f g h i x = case x of ...` to avoid repeating the name `go` a lot. (Feel free to ignore, of course.)

Comment: @DanielWagner: well I added an implementation to the answer with `case` but with `go` as well to avoid the `(cataTr f g h i e1)` calls :)